# When I refresh my website I get a 404 in console only in IE11 and Edge, Angular 5, Tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular5, tomcat8

When I refresh my Angular 5 application in IE11 or Edge browser, it is showing 404 error response in developer console

My angular application is deployed in Tomcat server. I do not want to use useHash: true in router module

How to fix this 404 response error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to configure your server to provide index.html.
Refer this. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0):

Followed the angular documentation, working fine in all browsers.

[Angular Server configuration](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)